# Cannot detect service using Network Service Discovery (NSD) on Android

Tags: android, nsd

I'm a newbie trying to use NSD in an application I'm building to find peers running the same service on the same wifi network and connect to the it.

[Refer to code] I have one device running **HostActivity.java** and one running **GuestActivity.java**. Clicking the floating button in Host registers a service on port 9000 ( preset for now ) and clicking it in Guest starts running a service discovery for the same. Both are connected to the same wifi network.

In my logcat, I observe that registration from **HostActivity.java** works fine - I get the requisite log messages from **NsdHelper.java**. However, running **GuestActivity.java** just logs 'Service Discovery started' and never ends up resolving to the service that exists on the network.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Relevant code -

**HostActivity.java**

```
NsdHelper mNsdHelper;

public static final String TAG = "ABC";
private final int ABC_PORT = 9000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_list);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mNsdHelper = new NsdHelper(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Started Registration", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("CLOSE", null).show();
            mNsdHelper.initializeNsd();
            mNsdHelper.registerService(ABC_PORT);
            Snackbar.make(view, "Completed Registration", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mNsdHelper != null) {
        mNsdHelper.initializeNsd();
        mNsdHelper.registerService(ABC_PORT);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mNsdHelper.tearDown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**GuestActivity.java**

```
NsdHelper mNsdHelper;

public static final String TAG = "ABC";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_list);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mNsdHelper = new NsdHelper(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Searching for available services", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            mNsdHelper.initializeNsd();
            mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mNsdHelper != null) {
        mNsdHelper.initializeNsd();
        mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mNsdHelper.tearDown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**NsdHelper.java** - This contains all the NSD implementation details

```
public class NsdHelper {
    Context mContext;

    NsdManager mNsdManager;
    NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;
    NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;
    NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;

    private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.";

    private static final String TAG = "NsdHelper";
    private String mServiceName = "ABC";

    // First step : register a NsdServiceInfo object to advertise your service
    NsdServiceInfo mService;

    public NsdHelper(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
}


public void initializeNsd() {
    initializeRegistrationListener();
    initializeDiscoveryListener();
    initializeResolveListener();

}


// Check success of service registration
public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
            mServiceName = nsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
            Log.d(TAG, "Registered name : " + mServiceName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int arg1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Registration Failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unregistered");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        }

    };
}

public void registerService(int port) {
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    serviceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);

    mNsdManager.registerService(
            serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);

}

// To discover services of the type you're looking for on the network
public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {
    mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success : " + service);
            Log.d(TAG, "Host = "+ service.getServiceName());
            Log.d(TAG, "port = " + String.valueOf(service.getPort()));

            if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
            } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
            } else if (service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)){
                mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
            if (mService == service) {
                mService = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }
    };
}

public void discoverServices() {
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(
            SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}


// Connection handshake
public void initializeResolveListener() {
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

            if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                return;
            }
            mService = serviceInfo;
            int port = mService.getPort();
            InetAddress host = mService.getHost();
        }
    };
}

public void stopDiscovery() {
    if (mNsdManager != null) {
        mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
    }
}

public NsdServiceInfo getChosenServiceInfo() {
    return mService;
}

public void tearDown() {
    if (mNsdManager != null) {
        if (mRegistrationListener != null) {
            mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
        }
        if (mDiscoveryListener != null) {
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have never played with NSD, so I don't have any recommendations with respect to this code. In cases like this, I try to find some existing working code, then slowly modify that code until it does what I need it to do. Either I'll eventually figure out where I'm breaking things, or I get working code. :-) Google might have an NSD sample, and I seem to recall seeing that a recent Android conference (droidcon.it 2016?) had a presentation on NSD, which might include a working sample.

Comment: Most (all?) of the core NSD code is basically taken verbatim from http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html - so I can't really proceed with changes to it if the base from Google itself doesn't work. I've also looked at similar code that claims to work (albeit from 2 years ago) here - http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-wireless-connection-1/ But that doesn't hold up either. I'll look for droidcon presentations about the same - let's hope I can find something. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) was being called you would at least see your log statements. I am running a similar program on a couple of generic android tablets. Once the service can't be found I have to shut both devices off and then turn them on again. Using a quickboot restart does not work. This is a workaround, I am open to a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you followed the code sample on Android developer site, and there're two mistakes which block us:

1. In the `public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service)` method, the code to check service name is not correct. From my understanding, the other device in the same network could also use the same service naming, so remove the `if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName))` code block.
2. The same thing happens in the `public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo)` code block. please remove the `if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName))` code block.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but here the problem is "onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service)" method is not getting called even there are multiple devices connected to network. I am using SERVICE_TYPE is "_http._tcp."